# How do I create database tables for a craft cms plugin on install?

Tags: plugin-development, database, migration

I am absolutely new to craft plugin development and could not find any documentation on creating database tables specific to a new plugin. How are new tables created when a plugin is installed?

I am browsing through the source code for the `CocktailRecipes` plugin: https://github.com/adrianmacneil/cocktailrecipes/ and I cannot find how the `craft_cocktailrecipes_ingredients` table gets created when I install it.

Is it merely a matter of defining a record class like `CocktailRecipes_IngredientRecord` and then overriding the `getTableName` and `defineAttributes` methods?

Is that how craft cms builds the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's it, check out the [Records documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records) to learn more:

> Active record models (or “records”) are like models, except with a
>   database-facing layer built on top. On top of all the things that
>   models can do, records can:
>
> - **Define database table schemas**
> - Represent rows in the database
> - Find, alter, and delete rows

Also, you might find ["Creating Database Migrations"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/migrations) interesting.

Answer (score 4):

`PluginNameRecord.php` is how Craft installs database tables. You can also have multiple tables by using `PluginName_TableRecord.php` where 'Table' will be the name of the new table in the database.

Might also be worthwhile to mention that the cocktails recipe you linked to has a lot of issues as it has not been updated for the latest versions of Craft.

Sean Delaney updated that plugin and the new repository is here:

https://github.com/seandelaney/cocktailrecipes

Comment: The delete option doesn't work for the updated version. Any ideas why??